# Reading POST data

Tags: http, go

I have built a server with few endpoints, in 1 of them i am taking logs in post body and jwt token in the authorization header. In this API i parse the token, validate it and then get the body. It is working file but sometimes i get these errors while reading the body:

- client disconnected
- stream error: stream ID 3; CANCEL

Reading body:

```
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body) // r *http.Request
```

Why am i getting these errors and how can i resolve them? Thanks

EDIT: THe endpoint handler

```
func logs(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var auth classes.AuthToken
    // Validate token and get the needed data from it
    if err := dbAndAuth.ValTokAndGetD(r, &auth, tokenKey); err != nil {
        if err != nil {
            if err.Error() == "" {
                classes.LogError(false, "got an empty error")
            }
            errD := classes.Resp{
                Success: false,
                Message: err.Error(),
                ErrCode: http.StatusUnauthorized,
            }
            json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(errD)
            return
        }
    }

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body) // Got the error here
    // parse the body to get the data
```

Comment: please put your code in the question, only one line of code is not enough

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of the code it is hard to answer, but the likely answer is that the stream is being closed before it can all be read.

This could be due to the body being closed (or any other means of manually closing prematurely).

Or the parsing is being run in a separate routine which isn't given chance to complete and respond in a [buffered?] channel back before the request completes.